# Show that every element on $O(\mathbb{R} ^2)$ is either a rotation or reflection

Tags: group-theory, reflection

Where $O(\mathbb{R} ^2)$ is the orthogonal group of $\mathbb{R} ^2$ or;

The set of all linear maps $g: \mathbb{R} ^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} ^2$ represented by an $n \times n$ matrix $M$ w.r.t. the standard basis of $\mathbb{R} ^2$ such that $M M^T$ is the identity matrix

I'm really not sure how to go about this?

Comment: What is your definition of $O(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

Comment: That would be helpful, ill pop it into the question

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea : 
You need to first show that the orthogonal matrices in $\mathbb R^2$ are of the form either

\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos \theta & -\sin\theta \\
    \sin\theta & \cos\theta \\
  \end{bmatrix}
 or

\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos \theta & \sin\theta \\
    \sin\theta & -\cos\theta \\
  \end{bmatrix} 
Hence you can conclude that either it is a reflection or a rotation . 
I hope that helps .

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go in a sec